# How to print the string @"123/456/789" in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a long text paragraph in which there is a string similar to "123/456/789". When I tried to use UIWebView to display it, the UIWebView always insert something like there is a web link there (an extra underscore and blue color, like [123/456/789](http://www.) with underscore). But I only want the normal black color just like others. Why does UIWebView add those "link" automatically? How can I avoid that?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Its taking it to be a link(URL)..Try using the HTML label tag to do it

Comment: Thanks, warrenm. Looks like it is duplicate. But I did not find that one. Wording is too important when you do a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the work of a data detector. The web view can automatically detect certain kinds of data, like phone numbers, and make them tappable links. This is often nice, because it's much easier to tap a phone number to make a call than to have to remember it and dial it yourself.

You can specify which types of data the web view should detect by setting its `dataDetectorTypes` property.